# How can Actor's position be reset on Orientation change in Libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
}
```

On above code, everything seems perfect on starting orientation(let's say portrait). But if orientation changes to landscape, then viewport scales down with black bars. Coming back to portrait everything goes to starting position again. Also, on stage's height/width seems unchanged.

Then I tried following code :

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
    stage.getCamera().viewportWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    stage.getCamera().viewportHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    System.out.println("-- stage width : " + stage.getWidth() +
                        "--- stage height : " + stage.getHeight());
    setImageObjectStage(); //<-- reset actors position in stage, not working
}
```

I have set activity to handle orientation change by code in manifest to stop restarting of libgdx game/screen.

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MainMenuActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"/>
```

Now, on orientation change from portrait to landscape, stage's width/height changes as desired. But at landscape view, everything seems black. It seems actor position is out of screen. All the actor's position is set relative to stage's dimension so, by logic they should have been drawn in stage. I don't have idea what is going wrong.

So, specific question is how to handle orientation change in libgdx without reloading the screen. Thanks,

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be setting the camera's viewportWidth and height manually, since those are managed by the Viewport. Need to see your `setImageObjectStage()` method to help more.

Comment: in setimageobjectstage(), image actors are set to their position. For eg : avatarBtnImage.setPosition(stage.getWidth()/2-avatarBtnImage.getWidth()/2,stage.getHeight()/2);

Comment: Shouldn't the camera position be part of that formula? I would think buttons need to be positioned relative to the camera so you can be sure they are on the screen.

Comment: I use default camera of stage. On screen constructor I have      
viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        stage = new Stage(viewport); ... I don't have enough knowledge on libgdx. I just assumed that, if on resize I can reset stage to change it's height, width followed by actor's position change. Then, actors can be repositioned properly to adapt to new orientation.

Comment: You either need to add a `true` to your `viewport.update` call's parameters to move the camera to where 0, 0 is the lower left corner, or you need to manually move your camera to where you want it. Since you never move your camera, 0.0 is always at the center of the screen, so right now you are positioning your objects just to the right of the top right corner of the screen.

Comment: @Tenfour04, Thanks. ya I had to use true for that. I got it working now by using following lines of code in resize().                      stage.getViewport().setWorldSize(width, height);    
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height,true);